# error line: 43 compiler: expected identifier or '(' before ' [ ' token

Tags: c, typedef

I have this problem with the line 43, I dont know why

if I dont write that line, the error does not appear, I've seen the code for a while and I havent found why it appears

the error is here

```
/*for(i=0;i<MAX_ESTACIONES;i++){
        Estaciones[i].nobici=10;     //the problem is this line
    }
*/
```

and this is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<time.h>

#define MAX_ESTACIONES 10
#define MAX_CARACTERES 40
#define MIN_CARACTERES 20

typedef char tipodato;
typedef struct info
{
    tipodato nombre[MAX_CARACTERES];
    tipodato edad[MIN_CARACTERES];
    tipodato sexo[MIN_CARACTERES];
    tipodato curp[MIN_CARACTERES];
    tipodato domicilio[MAX_CARACTERES];
    tipodato nacimiento[MAX_CARACTERES];
    tipodato comentario[MAX_CARACTERES];
    tipodato contrasenia[MAX_CARACTERES];
    int prestamo;
    struct info *sig;
}Persona;

typedef struct
{
    int nobici;
    clock_t inicio,fin;
} Estaciones[MAX_ESTACIONES];

typedef Persona *Listapersona;
Listapersona L;


int main()
{
    Persona *posicion;
    Persona *P;
    P=NULL;
    posicion=NULL;
    int opcion,salir,i;
    salir=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_ESTACIONES;i++){
        Estaciones[i].nobici=10;     //the problem is this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which IDE you're using?

Comment: Get rid of `typedef` from second `struct`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use minimal test cases.

Answer (score 8):

The `typedef` makes `Estaciones` the name of a type, and not a variable as you intended:

```
typedef struct
{
    int nobici;
    clock_t inicio,fin;
} Estaciones[MAX_ESTACIONES];
```

Remove the `typedef` to make it a variable, or make both a type and variable:

```
typedef struct
{
    int nobici;
    clock_t inicio,fin;
} TheStructName;

TheStructName Estaciones[MAX_ESTACIONES];
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I understand more  :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the typedef in `typedef struct ... Estaciones[...]`. You are obviously trying to define `Estaciones` as a type and use it as a variable. Also, instead of using `typedef struct { ... } Name;`, you should really use `struct Name { ... };` nowadays.

Comment: Thank you :), Now I understand more of this